# Recursive function to find the number of continuous sub-sequences in an array having a sum in the given range

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, subsequence

I wrote this `code`. The idea is to split the `array` into `2` parts and find the number of sub-sequences that satisfy the given condition. Now there can also be a sub-sequence with elements from both `subarrays`. Hence I wrote the crossub function.

The `subarray` function is going on an infinite `loop` (It's continuously printing the debug statement `"BBBBBBBB"`). I spent some time on this, but I guess I need some help.

**Note** : New to programming. I know the code is a piece of shit. But I am getting better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void crossub(int * A,int mid, int start, int end, int lbound, int ubound, int **k)
{
    int leftsum  = A[mid];
    int crossum;
    int rightsum = 0;
    int i;int j;
    for(i = mid -1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        leftsum = leftsum + A[i];
        for(j = mid +1; j <=end; j++)
        {
            rightsum = rightsum + A[j];
            crossum = rightsum + leftsum;
            if (lbound <= crossum && crossum <= ubound) k++;
            else if(crossum > ubound) break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
void subarray(int * A, int start, int end, int lbound, int ubound, int *count)
{
    printf("BBBBBBBBB ");
    if(start == end) 
    {
        if(lbound <= A[start] && A[start] <= ubound)
        {
            count++;
        }
       return;
    }
    int **k; int mid;
    k = &count;
    while (start <= end)
    {
    mid = (start + end)/2;
    subarray(A, start, mid,lbound,ubound,count);
    subarray(A, mid +1, end,lbound,ubound,count);
    crossub(A, mid, start, end, lbound,ubound,k);
    }
    return;
}

int numRange(int* A, int n, int lbound, int ubound) 
{
    // printf("AAAAAAAAAAA");
    int p = 0;
    int *count;
    count = &p;
    subarray(A, 0, n-1,lbound,ubound, count);

    return p;
}
int main()
{
    int A[] = {30, 5,1,0,2, 15,20,25};
    int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    printf("%d", n);
    int lbound = 6; int ubound = 8;
    int k = numRange(A, n,lbound, ubound);
    printf("%d ", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The array contains non-negative elements.

Comment: Use the *debugger* and single-step through your program. At what point is the program flow not as you would expect it?

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 4) variable names (and parameter names) should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your infinite loop, the issue is in the `subarray` function, namely:

```
while (start <= end)
{
    mid = (start + end)/2;
    subarray(A, start, mid,lbound,ubound,count);
    subarray(A, mid +1, end,lbound,ubound,count);
    crossub(A, mid, start, end, lbound,ubound,k);
}
```

As you can see, this is going to keep going forever, because you never change the values of start/end, so you keep calling `subarray` on the same section.

Although, as already stated by the first answer, this might not be the best way, but you can remove the while loop and see if it works, even if it might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that recursion is relevant here. The way here is to always have a range and check its sum. Initial range should contain the single first item (range can be defined via start and end indexes), initial value for sum should be equal to value of . Further processing is:

- If your sum is less than you're looking for, expand range incrementing its end index and adding value of new item to current value of range's sum;
- If your sum is greater than you're looking for, reduce range incrementing its start index and substracting value of excluded item from range's sum;
- If your sum is OK for you, return it.

Dealing with ranges:

- If your sum is less than you're looking for, and you're unable to increment its end index because it points to the last item in array you're looking through, you may return a result that says no range is satisfying your requirements;
- If your sum is greater than you're looking for, and you're unable to increment its start index because it points to the last item in array, you may also return same "no answer" result.

I'm sure there is no efficient way of dealing with ranges using "divide and conquer" strategy.